# Creating combined distribution for composite Gradle build

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I've got a modular Java project that combines libraries and CLI tools:

- cli-tools/

  - create-patch
  - find-conflicts
- modules/

  - core
  - analysis

I'm trying to create a combined distribution from the cli-tools project which contains all the dependency jars and all the launch scripts generated by the `application` plugin. I've got the build dependencies working, and my local jars are being included, but the launch scripts are not being included, and neither is anything from the `runtimeClasspath`s. My logging statement shows no plugins on any of the subprojects, even though their tasks are being executed, so maybe my method of checking for plugins is wrong?

```kotlin
// cli-tools/build.gradle.kts:

tasks.named("distZip").configure {
    subprojects.forEach {
        dependsOn(it.path.plus(":startScripts"))
    }
}

distributions {
    main {
        distributionBaseName.set("patch-tools")
        contents {
            project.subprojects.forEach { sub ->
                val subLibs = sub.buildDir.resolve("libs")
                if (subLibs.exists())
                    into("lib") {
                        from(subLibs)
                    }

                sub.logger.info("plugins of {}: {}", sub.name, sub.plugins)
                if (sub.pluginManager.hasPlugin("application")) {
                    into("lib") {
                        from(sub.configurations.findByName("runtimeClasspath"))
                    }
                    into("bin") {
                        from(sub.buildDir.resolve("scripts"))
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get this working so launch scripts and transitive dependencies are included in the distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to manually collect the individual pieces of the subproject distributions from the subproject build directories, I would recommend to rather let the subprojects create their complete distributions first and then to let the parent project combine those into a new one. This also has the advantage that you won’t miss any non-default/special pieces of the subproject distributions in the combined distribution (like docs or other directories).

Here’s how your `cli-tools/build.gradle.kts` could then look like:

```kotlin
plugins {
    distribution
}

tasks.named<Zip>("distZip") {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}

distributions {
    main {
        distributionBaseName.set("patch-tools")
        project.subprojects.forEach { sub ->
            sub.afterEvaluate {
                tasks.all { task ->
                    if (task.name == "installDist") {
                        contents.from(task)
                    }
                    true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `distZip` task (via the distribution `contents` `CopySpec`) now automatically depends on the `installDist` tasks of the subprojects and produces a combined distribution from their outputs.

(successfully tested with Gradle 7.3.2)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this line:

```
dependsOn(it.path.plus(":startScripts"))
```

should rather be:

```
dependsOn(":startScripts")
```

... because one cannot mix path with module name; there's also no sub-modules available. However, by the question it's not perfectly clear, if `:startScripts` is a task or a module.

Comment: the task dependencies seem to be working as-is, though it's possible they would break if the directory name didn't match the module name